# Unable to install PyAutoGui on Linux

Tags: python, linux, pyautogui

I'm trying to install **pyautogui**, and have an error.
I tried to install pyautogui on older python version, and have same error.
I also tried to install all dependencies separately, and got same error.

Command I ran:

> python3.10 -m pip install pyautogui

Python version: 3.10.2

Pip version: 22.0.4

Error:

```
  × Building wheel for pymsgbox (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [60 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib
      creating build/lib/pymsgbox
      copying src/pymsgbox/_native_win.py -> build/lib/pymsgbox
      copying src/pymsgbox/__init__.py -> build/lib/pymsgbox
      running install
      running install_lib
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/excl/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/excl/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/excl/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 230, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 13, in <module>
          setup(
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 335, in run
          self.run_command('install')
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 68, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/install.py", line 622, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
          self.finalize_options()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 17, in finalize_options
          self.set_undefined_options('install',('install_layout','install_layout'))
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 290, in set_undefined_options
          setattr(self, dst_option, getattr(src_cmd_obj, src_option))
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 103, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: install_layout. Did you mean: 'install_platlib'?
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymsgbox
Failed to build pyscreeze pymsgbox
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyscreeze, pymsgbox, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: That's something for a bug report, not for a SO question. Please, as a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with using an older version of dependencies and an older version of pyautogui (0.9.52).

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to specify which older version of the dependencies and pyatogui you used? That will help future readers who run into similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact issue with other packages after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, and it apparently comes from setuptools. Following this: [pypa/setuptools#3278](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3278)

I tried to run: `export SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib` in a terminal, and it worked like a charm!